# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I have a problem with one of my forms.

```
<%= form_for [@listing, @bike, @photo], html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
    <div class="custom-file col-sm-10 mt-4">
      <%= f.file_field :attachment, class: "custom-file-input" %>
      <label class="custom-file-label">Ajouter une photo</label>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Enregistrer", class: "btn btn-primary float-sm-right mt-4" %>
<% end %>
```

When I browse a new file and click on the submit button, everything is working fine. But when I I click on the submit button without browsing any picture, I get this error :

> ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: photo):

The form is put inside my index.html.erb. There is my controller methods :

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_listing, :find_bike

  def index
    @photos = @bike.photos
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
    if @photo.save
        flash[:success] = "Photo ajoutée avec succès"
        redirect_to listing_bike_photos_path(listing_id: @listing, bike_id: @listing.bike)
    else
        flash[:error] = @photo.errors.values
        redirect_to listing_bike_photos_path(listing_id: @listing, bike_id: @listing.bike)
    end
  end

  private

  def photo_params
        params.require(:photo).permit(:id, :attachment, :legend).merge(bike_id: @bike.id)
  end

  def find_listing
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
  end

  def find_bike
    @bike = Bike.find(params[:bike_id])
  end

end
```

And here, my routes :

```
resources :listings, except: [:show, :edit] do
    resources :bikes, except: [:edit] do
      resources :photos
    end
end
```

I suppose that I have made something wrong. But I cannot see where the problem comes from. Could someone help me to find the problem ? Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is my Photo model :

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bike, optional: true

  has_attached_file :attachment, styles: { medium: "300x300#", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

  validates :attachment, presence: true
end
```

And my related logs :

> Started POST "/listings/10/bikes/10/photos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-06 09:32:13 +0200
>   Processing by PhotosController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MV4dOYOFinOZsJjr+LlFRMIsDtQyPOxmlaV6PhEUZ1I+l5QS/bvwBRWc/EXLuw59F/B1Rgt6/5r79+bCiq3h6w==", "commit"=>"Enregistrer", "listing_id"=>"10", "bike_id"=>"10"}
>     User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
>     Listing Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `listings`.* FROM `listings` WHERE `listings`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
>     Bike Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `bikes`.* FROM `bikes` WHERE `bikes`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
>   Completed 400 Bad Request in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
>
> ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: photo):
>
> app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:36:in `photo_params'
>   app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:15:in`create'
>     Rendering /Users/virginie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
>     Rendering /Users/virginie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
>     Rendered /Users/virginie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (4.5ms)
>     Rendering /Users/virginie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
>     Rendered /Users/virginie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.1ms)
>     Rendering /Users/virginie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
>     Rendered /Users/virginie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.3ms)
>     Rendered /Users/virginie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (108.1ms)

And here the schema of my table :

```
create_table "photos", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT 
CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "bike_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
    t.string   "attachment_file_name"
    t.string   "attachment_content_type"
    t.integer  "attachment_file_size"
    t.datetime "attachment_updated_at"
    t.string   "legend"
  end
```

Comment: add code for photo model

Comment: Photo model added ;-)

Comment: Add related piece of Rails log.

Comment: related logs added

Comment: Where does the `legend` attribute come from?

Comment: It is a table attribute. But I don't use it yet.

Comment: I am not familiar with multi-model forms in Rails but you can shine some light on the issue by checking what parameters your browser is submitting to the server. In Chrome DevTools click on Network, then click on your "Enregistrer" button. This will create a new entry in the Network list with the name of the endpoint for your POST. Click on that name and then click on Headers. Scroll to the bottom to see what the browser's actually posting. It sounds as though it's not POST-ing in the expected format for your controller and missing a photo: key.

Comment: @Wivi0 you added the validation for attachment `  validates :attachment, presence: true` , remove validation if you don't require it

Comment: Removing my validation doesn't change anything. Here is what the browser is actually posting : "7k6PJOxVBe7tA+mpoBHK7hFZcA16VtQBLHMgax0lodPhhwYPkmt/mGEvjQeTE4HXxIULn0MQx/1CIbyXhpwnag==
------WebKitFormBoundaryVkNEjjeCtALPDHEP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo[attachment]"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream". I can not see if the problem comes to that or not.